# Google Calendar API: Embed Event invitation in Newsletter

Tags: google-api, google-calendar-api

I have been working with Google Calendar API for quite a while now.
Wrote python scripts to create events, edit events and invite guests.
But later I figured that it does not let me invite more than 500 guests to a particular event.
So I thought of adding the Event Invitation via our own mail system. For eg:
[image]

As shown in the image above, Calendar event details are added above the newsletter. My question is, how to embed this in our own newsletter?

Answer (score 1):

You could take a look into sending an ics file together with the newsletter. The iCalendar format is defined by RFC 5545 https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc5545